# How to avoid NIL from getting added to the list?

Tags: lisp

I'm a newbie in lisp. I've written a flatten function in lisp.

```
(defun flatten (list)
  (cond ((null list) nil)
        ((atom (first list))
         (cons (first list) (flatten (rest list))))
        (t (append (flatten (first list)) (flatten (rest list))))))
```

INPUT-
`(flatten '(a () b (c d)))`

Expected OUTPUT- `(a b c d)`

My OUTPUT- `(a nil b c d)`

What should I do avoid 'nil' from getting added to the list? I'm supposed to make a single recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NIL`, while doubling as `the empty list`, is still an `atom`.

```
CL-USER> (atom nil)
T
CL-USER> (atom '())
T
CL-USER>
```

If you need to ignore it, you'll need to change that second clause to check for `NIL` specifically.

```
...
((and (atom (first list)) (not (null (first list)))) ...)
...
```

Another option is changing your base case so that it gracefully handles `NIL`s in its first return value.

Answer (score 1):

`(atom nil) ; ==> T` and of course since `()` is `nil` you need to make a new base case that just recurse instead of consing when it's nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that NIL is both an empty list and an atom. So `(atom nil)` is true, but you want to view it as an empty list instead. To fix this, you need to handle `(first list)` being nil separately.